# Google Interactive Maps adding markers from database values

Tags: django, google-maps

I'm going to be storing records with lat/lng values in a database. I want to have a Google Interactive Map that will show all of these locations at once. I'm not completely familiar with the Google Maps API yet so I am unsure as to which way to go about doing things.

Can I..

Create an interactive map, embed it onto a page and when users click to add a marker, intercept the event, submit a form via off to my server that will store the values in the DB, and on success, add the location to the map? Do added markers get stored on google's side like that?

Or can I...

Simply show an embedded map, and when the map loads, loop over my database objects and create markers based on their lat/lng values? Will that lead to high loading times when there are lots of markers?

Of the two I prefer the latter option, but I'm not sure which is the most viable.

Comment: Yes you can create an interactive map. Yes, when a user clicks the map you can intercept that and store the location in your database. I don't know if Google does it that way though. I would suggest getting the markers from your database and THEN load the map.

Comment: Ok, is that the way that everyone generally uses? I guess the number of records got to the point where it was seriously slowing down the loading I'd have to look into filtering them somehow. If you want to chuck up your reply as an answer I'll accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are able to create an interactive map where you can intercept the users click and stoe the location in the database.
You can do something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
    // Catch click location from event
});
```

To get the location where is clicked.

Not sure how Google does it.

But would also suggest loading the markers from your database before you load the map.

How many markers do you have stored in your database that it is slowing down the process?

You could create a JSON / XML file and load the first x number of markers and load your map. After your map has loaded load the remaining markers (bit by bit).